# Spring Data JPA findOne returns null

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Spring Data JPA and I'm facing a very weird issue with findOne method which is returning null even though the row is present in DB.

I have a consumer thread which takes an id from a queue and tries to fetch the entity from DB which always returns null, however if I pause thread (by putting a breakpoint before method call) then it fetches the entity from DB but returns null in normal execution of program, I know it sounds weird with breakpoint stuff but it is what it is, may be I'm missing something. My code looks like below:-

```
     if (id > 0) {
      employee = employeeService.get(id);
      if (employee == null) {
            logger.error(String.format("No employee found for id : %d",
                        id));
            return;
     }
```

I'm not using any transaction in "employeeService" as it is not required as it is a read operation.

My service looks like

```
public Employee get(long id) {
    return employeeDao.findOne(id);
}
```

And my model looks like:-

```
   @Entity
   @Table(name = "employee")
   @JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
   public class Employee implements Serializable {

   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1681182382236322985L;

     @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     private long id;

    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "emplopyee_id")
    @Fetch(FetchMode.SELECT)
    private List<Address> addresses;

  // getter/setter and few fields have been omitted
```

}

Can somebody point me where I'm mistaking.

Comment: Not needing a transaction for read operations is a myth. You should have a transaction for every access to Hibernate. Isolation (the I in ACID) is important, too, and requires transactions.

Comment: I tried using transaction and marked it as readOnly but still I'm getting null value.

Comment: Can you show the relevant code in `employeeService.get` and the entity mapping please?

Comment: @Naros, updated question

Comment: If it returns `null` the record isn't there... My guess items are placed on the queue before the actual sender has had time to actually persist the record into the database. Make sure the messages (ids) are send after the transaction on the sender side has committed and has ended.

Comment: @M.Deinum, actually when an employee is persisted then a message (employee id) is put into queue into same service call, my wild guess is that the transaction is not committed by then and thus when consumer thread tries to read it, it gets null value, however I'm now able to get the employee record by using isolation level as READ_UNCOMMITTED, but that's not a good practice, is there any better solution to achieve same

Comment: As stated only put the message on the queue after the transaction has ended not inside the transaction. If you do that, you get the behavior you have now.

Comment: thanks for the confirmation, I've modified code to put message after transaction and it's working like charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Spring 4.2 way to do this would be to introduce a `@TransactionEventListener` annotated method on a spring component to handle the callback.  You then simply need to publish an event and let the event framework do its thing:

```
// Spring component that handles repository interactions
@Component
public class ProducerService implements ApplicationContextAware {
  private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

  @Transactional
  public void doSomeThingAwesome(String data) {
    MyAwesome awesome = new MyAwesome( data );
    myAwesomeRepository.save( awesome );
    applicationContext.publishEvent( new MyAwesomeSaved( awesome.getId() ) );
  }
}

// Spring component that handles the AFTER_COMMIT transaction callback
// This component only fires when a MyAwesomeSaved event is published and
// the associated transaction it is published in commits successfully.
@Component
public class QueueIdentifierHandler {
  @TransactionalEventListener
  public void onMyAwesomeSaved(MyAwesomeSaved event) {
    Long entityId = event.getId();
    // post the entityId to your queue now
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, that's great, thanks a lot for such a wonderful solution.